# Overfull \hbox warning. Table is cut off at the end. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Tags: tables, math-mode, overleaf

```
\begin{table}[!h]\centering

    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}

    \hline

        \textbf{Step} & \textbf{Know}     
                                   & \textbf{Reason}                                            \\ \hline
        P             & $x$ is an even integer and $y$ is an odd integer                         & Hypothesis                                                 \\ \hline
        P1            & There exists  $m$ and $n$ in the set of all integers, such that          & Definition of even and odd integers                               \\
                      & $x = 2m$ and $y = 2n +1$                         &                                                            \\ \hline
        P2            & $x + y = 2m + 2n + 1$                         &  Substitution of $x = 2m $ and $y = 2n +1$ into $x + y$ \\ \hline
        P3            & $x+y=2(m+n)+1 $                           & Algebra                                                    \\      &                                                           \\ \hline
        P4            & $(m+n)$ is in the set of all integers                          & Closure property of the integers under addition            \\ \hline
        P5            & there exist $q$ in the set of all integers, such that $x+y = 2q+1$                & Conclude that $2(q)+1$ is an integer                                      \\
                      &                                         &                                                            \\ \hline
        Q             & $x + y$ is odd                  &  Definition of an odd integer                           \\ \hline
        \textbf{Step} & \textbf{Know}                                        & \textbf{Reason}                                            \\ \hline
   
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  You don't say what document class you're using, or how wide the page is.  But the content of some of the cells in this table is very wide, and you have allowed only one line in each cell for its content.  It's not surprising that the final table is "cut off".  Change the `l` format for at least the second and third columns to a paragraph style, with the width specified so that the total width does not exceed the width of the text block.

Comment: use something line `lp{4cm}p{4cm}` rather than `lll` and see the general answers on wide tables in the referenced post.